# The switch/if statement breaks the for loop

Tags: javascript

I've spent 3 hours so far trying to fix the for loop. I've tried everything... If I remove the switch/if statement, the for loops works fine. Please advise.

Context: [This is an exercise where a grid of 1000x1000 lights has to be turned on/off by following a set of instructions with coordinates.](http://adventofcode.com/day/6)

This code is ok. I declare the objects and functions here.

```
var data = ["toggle 461,550 through 564,900", "turn off 370,39 through 425,839", "turn on 599,989 through 806,993"];

var instructions = []; //301

for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
var instruction = data[i].match(/\d+/g);
    if(data[i].match(/on/)) instruction.splice(0, 0, "on")
    else if(data[i].match(/off/)) instruction.splice(0, 0, "off")
    else if(data[i].match(/toggle/)) instruction.splice(0, 0, "toggle")

    instructions.push(instruction);
    console.log("Instructions populated.");
}

function Light(x, y, s) { // Constructor
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.s = s;
}

var lights = []; // The grid

for(x = 0; x < 10; x++) {// Populates the grid
    for(y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        lights.push(new Light(x, y, false));
    }
    console.log("Grid populated.");
}

function turnOn(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    for (i = 0; i < lights.length; i++) {
        if(lights[i].x >= x1 && lights[i].x <= x2 
        && lights[i].y >= y1 && lights[i].y <= y2) {
            lights[i].s = true;
        }
        //console.log(lights[i]);
    }
    console.log("Turning on DONE");
}

function turnOff(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    for (i = 0; i < lights.length; i++) {
        if(lights[i].x >= x1 && lights[i].x <= x2 
        && lights[i].y >= y1 && lights[i].y <= y2) {
            lights[i].s = false;
        }
    }
    console.log("Turning off DONE");
}

function toggle(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    for (i = 0; i < lights.length; i++) {
        if(lights[i].x >= x1 && lights[i].x <= x2 
        && lights[i].y >= y1 && lights[i].y <= y2) {
            lights[i].s = !lights[i].s;
        }
    }
    console.log("Toggling DONE");
}
```

This is the problematic part. I have no idea why it won't work.

```
console.log("For Loop start");
for(i = 0; i < instructions.length; i++){

    var action = instructions[i][0];
    var x1 = instructions[i][1];
    var y1 = instructions[i][2];
    var x2 = instructions[i][3];
    var y2 = instructions[i][4];
    console.log(action, x1, y1, x2, y2);

    switch(action){ // This breaks the loop.
        case "on": 
            turnOn(x1, y1, x2, y2); 
            break;
        case "off": 
            turnOff(x1, y1, x2, y2); 
            break;
        case "toggle": 
            toggle(x1, y1, x2, y2); 
            break;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

Instructions populated.
Grid populated.
For Loop start
toggle 461 550 564 900
Toggling DONE

**Why wont the other two instructions fire?**

Answer (score 1):

```
function toggle(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    for (i = 0; i < lights.length; i++) {
```

`toggle` reuses `i` and since there is no `var i` inside this function, it's using the `i` from the outer scope. Namely, your loop.

Comment: Instead of/in addition to renaming the variable, you really should declare it like: `for(var i=0;...` so when you add a variable `z` someplace else in your code it doesn't break again.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a global varible `i` in your for-loop and using the same in `toggle()` function, thus the loop ends.

Change all your for-loops to:

```
for(var i=0;...;...)
```